# Unique index with a lots of columns

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-design, unique-constraint

I have a busy OLTP table with 30 columns and 50 million rows, and I want to avoid duplicates in it.
What approach should I take?

So far I came up with these:

- direct unique index on 30 columns (sounds like a huge slow index)
- some sort of calculated unique index of sum of 30 columns
- an application-side generated hash placed in a new - 31th column with btree unique index

With the latter I feel like there will be a lot of hassle regenerating that hash-column if a table schema would change.

Maybe there are some other approaches that I didn't think of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Postgres 14

... just came out with a built-in hash function for ***records***, which is substantially cheaper than my custom function. Especially for many columns! See:

- [Generate hash id for records in DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69467639/generate-hash-id-for-records-in-db/69468763#69468763)

That makes the expression index much more attractive than a generated column plus index. So just:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_row_uni ON tbl (hash_record_extended(tbl.*,0));
```

This normally works, too:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_row_uni ON tbl (hash_record_extended(tbl,0));
```

But the first variant is safer. In the second variant `tbl` would resolve to the column if a column of the same name should exist.

#### Postgres 13 (original answer)

I provided a solution for that problem exactly on dba.SE recently:

- [Why doesn't my UNIQUE constraint trigger?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684)

It's pretty close to your third idea:

Basically, a very efficient server-side generated hash placed as 31th column with `UNIQUE` constraint.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_tbl_bighash(col1 text, col2 text, ... , col30 text)
  RETURNS bigint 
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS 
'SELECT hashtextextended(textin(record_out(($1,$2, ... ,$30))), 0)';

ALTER TABLE tbl
  ADD COLUMN tbl_bighash bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (public.f_tbl_bighash(col1, col2, ... , col30)) STORED  -- append column in last position
, ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_bighash_uni UNIQUE (tbl_bighash);
```

The beauty of it: it works efficiently without changing anything else. (Except, possibly, where you use `SELECT *` or `INSERT INTO` without target list or similar.)

And it works for `NULL` values, too (treating them as equal).

Careful if any column types have non-immutable text representation. (Like `timestamptz`.) The solution is tested with all `text` columns.

**If the table schema changes**, drop the `UNIQUE` constraint first, recreate the function and recreate the generated column - ideally with a single `ALTER TABLE` statement, so you don't rewrite the table twice.

**Alternatively**, use a `UNIQUE` expression index based on `public.f_tbl_bighash()`. Same effect. Upside: no additional table column. Downside: a bit more expensive, computationally.

Comment: but why not an expression based unique index then?

Comment: @Alez: A unique expression index is a valid alternative. I added a bit.

Comment: @Alez: this got even better with Postgres 14. Consider the update.

Comment: What is the probability of hash collision in this method?

Comment: @MehdiPourfar See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/299107/3684